# Object property null value even though it has a value

Tags: javascript, angular

this is a really weird thing happening.
Basically, I can print my 'data' object and see the property 'tempId' having a value.
However, immediately after, if I print data.tempId (or even data['tempId'], the value being returned is NULL.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to print `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))` to get the real value as the time you log [logging object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects)

Comment: Yup thats it, now it shows up as null. Thanks.